# How to customize a kbordermatrix

Tags: highlighting, bordermatrix

To the matrix given below, I would like to add the following two features:

1. A downarrow centered below the text "Column j."
2. Highlight the entry a_{ij}.

How might I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \kbordermatrix{{}&{}&{}& \mbox{Column $j$} &{}&{} \\
    {} & a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1j} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
    {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
    \mbox{Row $i \rightarrow$ }   & a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{ij} & \cdots & a_{in} \\
    {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
    {} & a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mj} & \cdots & a_{mn}
    }
    \]
\end{document}
```

You may find kbordermatrix.sty [here](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml) under "Miscellany."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

- With the `stackengine` package, you will have ‘ annotations’ (for columns and rows) of the same size as the surrounding text.
- with the `substack` command, it will be `\scriptsize` by default; I changed it to `footnotesize`.

I also  an easily customisable `\hl` command for highlighting, based on the `\colorbox` command. It uses a `hlcolour` for the text and a `hlbgcolour` for the background of the box; you may change them at will with the `\colorlet` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\colorlet{hlbgcolour}{Thistle3!50!}
\colorlet{hlcolour}{VioletRed4}
\newcommand\hl[1]{\setlength\fboxsep{1.5pt}\colorbox{hlbgcolour}{\color{hlcolour}$#1 $}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \kbordermatrix{{}&{}&{}& \smash{\Shortstack{Column $ j $\\$ \downarrow $}} &{}&{} \\
    {} & a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1j} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
    {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
    \mbox{Row $i \rightarrow$ } & a_{i1} & \cdots & \hl{a_{ij}} & \cdots & a_{in} \\
    {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
    {} & a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mj} & \cdots & a_{mn}
  }
\]
\vskip4ex
\[
  \kbordermatrix{{}&{}&{}& \substack{\text{\footnotesize Column } j\\\downarrow} &{}&{} \\
    {} & a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1j} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
    {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
    \mbox{\everymath{\textstyle}\footnotesize Row $i \rightarrow$ } & a_{i1} & \cdots & \hl{a_{ij}} & \cdots & a_{in} \\
    {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
    {} & a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mj} & \cdots & a_{mn}
  }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `kbordermatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{r@{} *{5}{c}}
&&& \mathclap{\text{Column $j$}} \\
&&& \downarrow \\
\begin{block}{r@{}[*{5}{c}]}
 & a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1j} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
 & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
\text{Row $i \rightarrow{}$ }   & a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{ij} & \cdots & a_{in} \\
 & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
 & \,a_{m1}\, & \cdots & a_{mj} & \cdots & \,a_{mn}\, \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[renew-dots,xdots/shorten=6pt,first-row,first-col]
   & \Block{1-*}{\text{Column $j$} \\ \downarrow } \\
    & a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1j} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
    & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
   \text{Row $i \rightarrow$ }   & a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{ij} & \cdots & a_{in} \\
    & \vdots & {} & \vdots & {} & \vdots \\
    & \,a_{m1}\, & \cdots & a_{mj} & \cdots & \,a_{mn}\, \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]